# Using the mdframed package with the quoting package affects the position of enumerate numbering

Tags: positioning, enumerate, mdframed

In the following MWE, the second number in the enumerated list, namely `2.`, is moved inwards. This is clearly caused by use of the `\surroundwithmdframed` command. Is there some way to fix this while still using the `\surroundwithmdframed` command in the same way?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[vskip=10in]{quoting}
\surroundwithmdframed[linewidth=2pt]{quoting}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item An item.
  \item
    \begin{quoting}
      The \verb|\surroundwithmdframed| option moves the item number inwards.
    \end{quoting}
  \item Another item.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can do the same with `\item \mbox{}\par\vspace{-4\itemsep}
    \begin{quoting}...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `mdframed` based solution, but using `tcolorbox` and an automatic `\mbox{}` and some vertical upshift.

The `\tcolorboxenvironment` is basically the same what `\surroundwithmdframed` does.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{mdframed}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[vskip=10in]{quoting}
% \surroundwithmdframed[linewidth=2pt]{quoting}
\tcolorboxenvironment{quoting}{code={\mbox{}},nobeforeafter,before skip=-2\itemsep,boxrule=2pt,sharp corners,colback=white}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item An item.
  \item 
    \begin{quoting}
      The \verb|\surroundwithmdframed| option moves the item number inwards.
    \end{quoting}
  \item Another item.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the alternative suggestion, Christian. Can I skip the grayed out interior? It doesn't survive scanning and reprinting the scans very well.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I assume you prefer white background then? Add `colback=white` to the option list, e.g. after `sharp corners`

Comment: Yes, white background. Sorry, should have specified. Thanks.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: No problem.

Comment: Hi Christian, one issue with your alternative with your approach (which isn't an issue with `mdframed`), is that the boxes won't break across pages. This is a problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Note, the manual says that `tcolorbox` supposedly support breaking boxes across pages, but I tried `\tcbuselibrary{breakable}`, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Add `breakable` to the options list

Comment: to the options list of the command, where `colback` etc is used

Comment: Hi Christian. Ok, that works. Sorry for my cluelessness. However, I (slightly) prefer the way that `mdframed` breaks the boxes, because the facing lines are missing, making it clear it is a continuation of the previous quote. Any idea how one could do that?

Comment: Ah, looks like using the `skin=enhanced` option does the trick. Do I have this right?

Comment: Lines immediately before the boxes were disappearing, so I had to remove the `before skip=-2\itemsep`. What was the reason for including that option?

Comment: Sorry, I am offline the next days and can't updates